# Best way to calculated column in DB or SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When we have some calculated column in database for reports, which is best way to calculated it's value in case of SSRS report development.

1. Calculate it in SSRS tablix
2. Calculate it from database and return as dataset

If I am duplicating this question then sorry for that, but I didn't got proper answer while googling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, it depends.

- If the calculated value is fairly static then this favours a persisted
  computed column.
- If the calculated value is useful in multiple reports, then this
  favours the computed column
- If the report server and the reporting database are on the same SQL
  Server it may be a wash in terms of load,
- If the report db is on an OLTP server but the report server is on a
  different instance it favour the the tablix to move the load.
- There may also be a consideration for the nature of the calculation
  itself. Some may be more natural for one or the other.

I'm probably missing some, but the point is I don't believe that there is single right answer to the question.

Comment: Good points. Also, in SSRS you cannot do the aggregate of an aggregate easily(example: `avg(sum(Field.value))` will not work). In this case its easiest to do the `sum` in the query.

Comment: Thank you.
In case of simple calculation like addition or calculating percentage value of column? 
My consideration is to perform calculation in SSRS itself but I don't see any considerable performance issue.

Comment: vishaldk: From what you are saying your probably fine doing that simple math in the tablix.